# How to update data without existing ones getting affected in Swift and Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so in my app, users input data into the text field which has been saved and stored in my firebase database. But when the input is changed, it completely overrides what I had in the database before.

Here's the code;

```
    @IBAction func cont(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Database reference
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    //Referencing the actual table the data is updated and stored in
    let customerRef = ref.child("customerDetails")
    customerRef.updateChildValues(["email": emailTextField.text!])
    customerRef.updateChildValues(["firstName" : firstNTextField.text!])

}
```

Here's the image of my database;

[image]

There will be multiple data collected and I will be adding more fields such as last name and stuff into. So how can existing data not get affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this will allow you to add lists to your database, inside of customerDetails, without affecting any existing data. Also, you can just update your values in one line like so:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
let customerRef = ref.child("customerDetails").childByAutoId()
customerRef.updateChildValues(["email": emailTextField.text!,
                               "firstName": firstNTextField.text!])
```

Comment: is it possible to have the childByAutoId to be something specific like 1A, 1B etc...?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Firebase won't do this for you. You might want to do an observation first to get the count of all the children inside of customerDetails and plus 1 to that so no matter what, every time you update the values, it'll be named +1 more than the last on in there. Then you'll have a structure like 1, 2 , 3, 4 etc.